# Getting value for phone number and email address from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios8, addressbook

I'm trying to extract the phone number and email address from the address book on iOS8 and I open the person picker as follows:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty], nil];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When there are multiple phone numbers and multiple email addresses in the contact details, how do I select one of each?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to tick the preferred phone and then the preferred email address but it doesn't look like I can.

Anybody know how to do this please?